# load data in highcharts from 2 different csv files

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to find out if I can get a graph using 2 sources (one for the categories, another for the actual data plotted.

I find myself often in need to use the same category for different series; but I can't code in the chart itself, since they are not global. As example picture a temperature sensor data: it uses Celsius and my category fits in a specific user case; which apply to all my temperature sensors but if I need to use data coming from a pressure sensor, then I need to change unit of measure and other parameters in the category.

To alleviate; I can simply write functions on the fly, that generate directly from the server, a ton of specific csv files; but I thought that I can just grab bits and pieces instead from the files that the server already returns.

But I can't find an example about how would you set different files as source for the category and the series. Is this possible or should I just make a ton of ad hoc single csv files?

EDIT
I am using the standard example that is on the highcharts site, to load a csv file; it is not on JSFiddle so I can just paste the link to that web example: http://www.highcharts.com/studies/data-from-csv.htm

What I did was to duplicate the $.get function, using a different file name, but it won't work; so I tried to change also the data name, and that didn't work either:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {


                var options = {
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'container',
                        type: 'column'
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Fruit Consumption'
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: []
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'Units'
                        }
                    },
                    series: []
                };

                /*
                 Load the data from the CSV file. This is the contents of the file:

                    Apples,Pears,Oranges,Bananas,Plums
                    John,8,4,6,5
                    Jane,3,4,2,3
                    Joe,86,76,79,77
                    Janet,3,16,13,15

                 */ 
                $.get('data.csv', function(data) {
                    // Split the lines
                    var lines = data.split('\n');
                    $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
                        var items = line.split(',');

                        // header line containes categories
                        if (lineNo == 0) {
                            $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                                if (itemNo > 0) options.xAxis.categories.push(item);
                            });
                        }

                        // the rest of the lines contain data with their name in the first position
                        else {
                            var series = { 
                                data: []
                            };
                            $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                                if (itemNo == 0) {
                                    series.name = item;
                                } else {
                                    series.data.push(parseFloat(item));
                                }
                            });

                            options.series.push(series);

                        }

                    });

$.get('data2.csv', function(data) {
                    // Split the lines
                    var lines = data.split('\n');
                    $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
                        var items = line.split(',');

                        // header line containes categories
                        if (lineNo == 0) {
                            $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                                if (itemNo > 0) options.xAxis.categories.push(item);
                            });
                        }

                        // the rest of the lines contain data with their name in the first position
                        else {
                            var series = { 
                                data: []
                            };
                            $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                                if (itemNo == 0) {
                                    series.name = item;
                                } else {
                                    series.data.push(parseFloat(item));
                                }
                            });

                            options.series.push(series);

                        }

                    });

                    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
                });


            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find example how to load three files as series: http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/compare

So the only difference would be that you are using just one series, and second file will be used for categories data.

In above solution added is some global counter, to render chart after all files are received.

Second solution will be to call second AJAX inside callback for a first one, snippet:

```
$.getJSON(url1, function(data) {
    $.getJSON(url2, function(data2) {
        // create chart here
    });
});
```

Edit:

If you have two CSV files, this is what you need to change:

```
$.get(url1, function(data1) {
    $.get(url2, function(data2) {
        // parse data1
        var parsedData1 = ...
        // parse data2
        var parsedData2 = ...

        $("#container").highcharts({
           series: [{
               data: parsedData1
           }, {
               data: parsedData2
           }]
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Pawel; I will give a try to the compare example. The second solution looks simpler, but it could be deceiving; will give it a try tomorrow.

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish the same, but without JSON? I just want to grab data from different CSV files

Comment: File format doesn't matter. but when using CSV, you need to parse strings to proper format (just like in JSON).

Comment: Yeah, I am able to do so with one file, but I have no clue how do you implement it with 2 or more; since I get a blank canvas if I simply duplicate the $.get function, replacing only the CSV filename. Is there an example that I can use as template?

Comment: To be specific; I am using the CSV example from the highcharts site for the code; I am not able to figure out how do you exactly make different series from different files; and since there is no support for debugging step by step the JS code, I have no idea what am I doing wrong.

Comment: How do you load second file? You should load it inside of callback of the first one. Snippet: `$.get(function(data1) { $.get(function(data2) { .. create chart here .. });  });`

Comment: This is what I am trying to figure out... the example has one $.get('file.csv',function(data){}); and if I duplicate it, replacing data with data1 and using a different csv file, I get a blank canvas

Comment: Add code you have to the question, it would be really helpful.

Comment: Thanks Pawel, this is the function that I am using; is the same of the example; I would love to learn how can I grab a different file, so I can have multiple series on the same canvas

Comment: Okay, I'm a bit lost: in my example you see how to get two JSON's and it works fine, right? Now you just want to change from JSON to CSV. The only things you need to change is `$getJSON()` to `$.get()` AND write parser from strings (CSV is string) to numbers.

Comment: Sorry if it is not clear; I tried with the JSON but the data that I get is in CSV format, so I can't use that. I receive those files from a server; so I just abandoned the JSON example that you mentioned, and went for the CSV solution. Loaded one file and everything is fine, but I am having problems to understand how do you load more CSV files now. All that I am looking for is a snippet that actually show what changes between a $.get for one file, and for multiple files, because I can't figure that out, nor I can change variables at random

Comment: Thanks Pawel! So this is how it works; you nest the $.get, change the data name, and then in the options for the series, you use the data name related to each of the series. I really don't know how to thank you! This stuff should be straight on the example pages of the highcharts site IMHO. Trying this right now!

Comment: That was exactly the same I said 4 comments ago, you know? ;) I'm pretty sure you can find a lot of examples in jQuery docs. It's not Highcharts specific problem.

Comment: Yes, but it didn't click for me until I saw it in the edit; I started to use jQuery and Highcharts last week :) I know very little of Java in general, since I am using mostly C# and C++, so a snippet is the best way for me to learn how things works