# dynamic multiple series from different CSV-files

Tags: csv, highcharts

I have multiple CSV files that are updated regulary.
I can use the "Live data from dynamic CSV" example ( https://www.highcharts.com/demo/live-data) but it only uses 1 CSV file while I need to show multiple series all using seperate CSV files.

Currently I can only show one of the CSV files in the graph. I hope someone could for example show me how to show the example time-data.csv in the same graph twice as 2 seperate series.

```
function createChart() {

    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'spline'
        },
        yAxis: {
        max: 40,
        min: 15
    },
        title: {
            text: 'Live Data'
        },
        data: {
            csvURL: 'https://demo-live-data.highcharts.com/time-data.csv',
            enablePolling:  true,
            dataRefreshRate: 2
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highcharts does not have built-in functionality to load data from multiple CSV sources. You need to manually get data and parse it to the format required by Highcharts. For example:

```
var url1 = 'https://demo-live-data.highcharts.com/time-data.csv',
    url2 = 'https://demo-live-data.highcharts.com/time-data.csv';

function parseData(data) {
    var parsedData = [],
        splittedData = data.split(/\n/),
        splittedRow;

    splittedData.shift();

    splittedData.forEach(function(row) {
        splittedRow = row.split(',');
        parsedData.push([new Date(splittedRow[0]).getTime(), Number(splittedRow[1])]);
    });

    return parsedData;
}

$.get(url1, function(data1) {
    $.get(url2, function(data2) {
        // parse data1
        var parsedData1 = parseData(data1)
        // parse data2
        var parsedData2 = parseData(data2)

        Highcharts.chart('container', {
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime'
            },
            series: [{
                data: parsedData1
            }, {
                data: parsedData2
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/u93khtva/

**Useful thread:** [load data in highcharts from 2 different csv files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24053644/load-data-in-highcharts-from-2-different-csv-files)